# How can I set the Jbuttons in a preferred order?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a grid of 30 buttons, and I want to have it from left to right then goes down, right to left, down again left to right. Basically the numbering would be as follow:

1   2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11

21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30

So if I have a piece on the button 10 and I instruct it to move up 2 bits it would land on 12 not 19.

Below is my Code:

```
//Creates the button using the loop, adds it into the panel and frame.
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,10));
        JButton [] buttons = new JButton[30];
        for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
            buttons[i] = new JButton("label" + i);
            buttons[i].setBackground(Color.white);

        //Puts the player 1 piece on button 1,3,5,7,9 and player 2 piece on button 2,4,6,8,10
           if (i < 10) {
           if (i%2 == 0) {
             buttons[i].setIcon(piece1);
           } else {
             buttons[i].setIcon(piece2);
           }
        }
        panel.add(buttons[i]);
                    }

        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: I'll bet with a little simple logic and algebra, you'll be able to solve this yourself.

Comment: Mate, why are you after my case. Just because I didnt understood your question didn't mean I was being rude and ignored your help?

Comment: I'm not after nothing. I just thing that you should show an attempt to try to solve this first. I mean come on, this is trivially easy to do. Just a simple if statement and algebra will solve this. Don't you want to exercise your brain a bit before bailing out here?

Comment: I did leave you a comment regarding your solution but you didnt reply

Comment: I see no question from you in my previous answers.

Comment: @UmzzMo : I just faced some issues two more classes are missing, `ButtonExample and Dice` :(

Comment: Just tell me is this what you expecting, as the outcome, have a look at the image attached in the answer.

Comment: @nIcEcOw Yes thats how I want it to be.

Comment: Where to chat ? And yeah, since this program did worked, please do mark @HovercraftFullOfEels 's answer as correct :-) For the rest of the part, that is my PLEASURE :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example,

```
  for (int i = 1; i <= buttons.length; i++) { // avoid magic numbers

     int btnNumber = (i > 10 && i <= 20) ? (31 - i) : i;

     System.out.printf("i = %d, btnNumber = %d%n", i, btnNumber);
     buttons[btnNumber - 1] = new JButton("label " + btnNumber);
     buttons[btnNumber - 1].setBackground(Color.white);
     panel.add(buttons[btnNumber - 1]);
  }
```

Or the logic part can be written,

```
     if (i > 10 && i <= 20) {
        btnNumber = 31 - i;
     } else {
        btnNumber = i;
     }
```

But again, you should have been able to figure this out yourself, or at least shown us an attempt.

Or more generally:

```
  int rows = 5;
  int cols = 10;
  int textNumber = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++) {
     if ((i / cols ) % 2 == 0) {
        textNumber = i;
     } else {
        textNumber = ((i / cols) + 1) * cols - (i % cols) - 1;
     }
     textNumber++;
     System.out.printf("[%02d, %02d] ", i, textNumber);
     if ((i + 1) % cols == 0) {
        System.out.println();
     }
  }
```

Comment: The place where i am adding pieces on the buttons are giving me null error when I put the first code you gave in.

Comment: @UmzzMo: my code posted above is not meant to be plugged into your program unchanged, but is meant to give you an idea of how to solve your problem. You'll have to create your own code based on this idea. Then if it doesn't work or you get a NPE, you'll want to debug your code.

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand how it is doing what I want to. Can you explain what each steps are doing?

Comment: @UmzzMo :  Had you declared something like `JButton[] buttons = new JButton[30];`, as  your instance variable ? If yes then I guess the first example will work as it is :-)

Comment: @nIcEcOw Yes I have, when I do the first example it gives me a null error in                                                                                      if(i < 10) {
           if (i%2 == 0) {
             buttons[i].setIcon(piece1);
           } else {
             buttons[i].setIcon(piece2);
           }

Comment: @nIcEcOw sorry it didnt come out right, but its giving me an error in my other part of the code where I have set the pieces on the buttons

Comment: @UmzzMo : Are you sure that null error, as said by you is for the `JButton` array and not related to your `Image`, that you setting !! If  you may post the stack trace, that will be much helpful. Are you sure you understood, the logic well, since the first JButton of your second row is `buttons[19]`, according to that first example, do check that, might be you calling the wrong index at the wrong place :-)

Comment: @nIcEcOw quick question. Do I need to remove and replace my code by this or I just stick this in? I replaced the example code with my for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
            buttons[i] = new JButton("label" + i);
            buttons[i].setBackground(Color.white);

Comment: @UmzzMo : You can place that example code as is, in your case, it seems like, just remember, the first JButton of the first row is `buttons[0] then buttons[1]... so on` from left to right, but when you will access the first JButton of your second row it can be done by `buttons[19], buttons[18], buttons[17]... so on` from left to right.

Comment: nIcEcOw and @HovercraftFullOfEels, Thank you very much both of you for your help. Really appreciate both of you for your kind help. Especially nice cow. :)

Comment: @nIcEcOw are you there? I need help with the code you did for me

Comment: @UmzzMo : Ohh, yeah, Please do tell, in what way, Can I help you ?

Comment: @nIcEcOw I am having problem trying to move the pieces. Is there anyway we can talk online?

Comment: @nIcEcOw u there? Check ur email

Answer (score 1):

use netbeans' spring layouts to solve your problems
just design a couple of buttons in the design tab then replicate them in a loop with your desired counts.